# Translating Javascript to Pug

Tags: html, pug

How can I implement this in pug?

```html
<ul class="quotes">
  <% for(var i=0; i<quotes.length; i++) {%>
    <li class="quote">
      <span><%= quotes[i].name %></span>
      <span><%= quotes[i].quote %></span>
    </li>
    <% } %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

in pug you can use ForEach loop to pass through your quotes array.

```
ul
  each quot in quotes 
     li.quot
        span = quot.name
        span = quot.quot
```

Indentation is something necessary in the puge and here I type in myself so play with it 
 to the right tabs